# How do I get the content length of a Django response object?

Tags: django, http, httpresponse, content-length

In Django, I try to logging the request and response content length, which exactly the same as what Django server prints to stderr.

```
[05/Apr/2011 22:59:08] "GET /pages/ HTTP/1.1" 200 332161
[05/Apr/2011 22:59:15] "GET /pages/12 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[05/Apr/2011 22:59:15] "GET /pages/12/ HTTP/1.1" 200 361474
[05/Apr/2011 22:59:16] "GET /pages/12/load/tags/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13899
[05/Apr/2011 22:59:16] "GET /pages/12/load/comments/ HTTP/1.1" 200 82
```

So, I write a simple middleware as follows, but, the value of 'Content-Length' is always empty.

```
class LogHttpResponse(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        import datetime  
        print response.items()
        time_text = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
        print '[%s] "%s %s" %d %s' % (time_text, request.method, request.path, 
                                      response.status_code, 
                                      response.get('Content-Length', ''))
        return response
```

I've checked through fire-debug, **there is 'Content-Length' in the response headers**. But there is no 'Content-Length' in the middleware, "print response.items()" shows:

```
[('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')]
```

Is there any problem of the middleware orders?

Comment: If the `Transfer-Encoding` is `chunked` then there is no `Content-Length` header. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `len(response.content)`? That’d give you the number of characters in the response’s content. I guess that isn’t necessarily the same as the number of bytes.

Comment: if used inside class-based views, this will produce a `ContentNotRenderedError`
the correct answer is above - find Content-Length in the headers on the response

Comment: [HttpResponse.content is a bytestring](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.content)

Answer (score 17):

> I've checked through fire-debug, there is 'Content-Length' in the
>   response headers. But there is no 'Content-Length' in the middleware
>   [...] Is there any problem of the middleware orders?

Yes. Middleware classes are applied from top-down (in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`) when processing request and bottom-up when processing the response. If you have `'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware'` in you middleware classes it will add a `'Content-Length'` header to the HttpResponse.

Though if you put your middleware class after `'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware'` in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` it will apply this one first when processing the response and then apply the `ConditionalMiddleware` afterwards. That's why you see a `Content-Length` header in Firebug, though its not yet processed when you Middleware is called.

See [Django Middleware documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) for more information about Middleware's.

Comment: Note that the `Content-Length` header is now added to HttpResponse in `CommonMiddleware`.